# Q&A: how to mock kotlin top level extension functions in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, mocking

It is a self 'question and answer' post to track my issue and completed research on it.

I was a looking for an option to mock `WorkManager` (*). It utilise `LiveData` and its `asFlow()` extension function call. I was looking for a way to mock this `LiveData.asFlow()` call.

At this moment many answers was not a quite fit, so I decided write this new post.

(*) Code which uses `WorkManager` should be put within `androidTest` package, but my constrains pushed me to look for a workaround with plain `test` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Kotlin extensions` are recognised as `Java` static methods.

`Mockito` since v5 has built-in support of such functions. Before v5 it could be enabled manually.

However, by using `Mockito` I wasn't able to test `asFlow()` extension for a `LiveData`.

`Mockk` is an another alternative for a such scenario. The extra attention should be payed for `@file:JvmName("FlowLiveDataConversions")` as it overrides package name which should be defined in `mockkStatic(<full path>)`.

```
        val flow = flow {
            val workInfo: WorkInfo
            workInfo = WorkInfo(UUID.randomUUID(), WorkInfo.State.SUCCEEDED, Data.EMPTY, emptyList(), Data.EMPTY, 0, 0)
            emit(workInfo)
        }
        mockkStatic("androidx.lifecycle.FlowLiveDataConversions")
        every {
            mockedLiveData.asFlow()
        } returns flow
        `when`(workManager.getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(any()))
            .thenReturn(mockedLiveData)
```